# Como enviar uma váriavel do php, num parâmetro de função javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu quero enviar uma váriavel do php ao chamar uma função do javascript.
Desse modo:

```
href="javascript:calcular($valor1)"
```

Eu tento fazer isso, parece não funcionar. Há alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Sugiro aprender a pesquisar no site. Tem mais de 200 perguntas (sério mesmo) com este assunto e exemplos diversos.

Answer (score 1):

Basta imprimir a variável usando a funcão `echo`

```
href="javascript:calcular(<?php echo $valor1; ?>)"
```

Comment: Ainda assim não passa. Eu criei uma função só pra fins de teste:  `function calcular(cod){ alert(cod);}` e não funcionou desse jeito.

Comment: Como fica  o código html gerado?

Comment: Não entendi o que tu quis dizer

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Eu faria assim:

```js
function calcular(element){
  var variavel = $(element).data('var');
}
```

```html
<a data-var="<?= $calcular ?>" onClick="calcular(this)">Clique</a>
```